# Rotate Quaternion by an offset?

Tags: unity-game-engine, quaternions

I'm trying to add an offset to the rotation of a quaternion, according to the [Unity documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-operator_multiply.html) multiplying two Quaternions is the same as doing both rotations in sequence.

This is what I'm trying now:

If the offset Quaternion is (0, 0, 0, 0) multiplying the first quaternion by it, shouldn't have any effect.  However in my tests multiplying any Quaternion by (0, 0, 0, 0) results in (0, 0, 0, 0), so this is not working correctly.

```
    Quaternion q = new Quaternion (-0.7f, 0f, 0f, -0.7f);
    Quaternion rotationZero = new Quaternion (0f, 0f, 0f, 0f); // offset

    Quaternion result = q * rotationZero;

    print (result); // (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

Comment: Actually, multiplying by (1,0,0,0) has no effect. Note that all quaternions used to represent rotations should have a magnitude of 1 (sum of squares = 1). Your `q` value is also a little off (it has a magnitude of about 0.99).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here the issue is not is C# or in Unity, the values you are using causes the output values to be       `(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)`. It can be mathematically explained as below.

The quaternions have the form of

`q = q0 + iq1 + jq2 + kq3`
and
`r = r0 + ir1 + jr2 + kr3`

The quaternion product has the form of

`t= q×r = t0 + it1 + jt2 + kt3`,
where

`t0 = (r0q0−r1q1−r2q2−r3q3)
 t1 = (r0q1+r1q0−r2q3+r3q2)
 t2 = (r0q2+r1q3+r2q0−r3q1)
 t3 = (r0q3−r1q2+r2q1+r3q0)`

Answer (score 1):

```
Quaternion q = new Quaternion (-0.7f, 0f, 0f, -0.7f);
Quaternion rotationZero = Quaternion.identity; // offset

Quaternion result = q * rotationZero;
```

[Quaternion.identity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-identity.html)